# In the divergence theorem of Gauss, where does $rdrd\theta$ come from?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

The text says:

> The form of the surface suggests that we introduce polar coordinates r, $\theta$ defined by x = r * $\cos{u}$, y = r * $\sin{u}$ (thus cylindrical coordinates r, u, z). Then the volume element is dx dy dz = r dr d$\theta$ dz...

Can someone explain where does that equivalence come from? Why does $x = r \cos{\theta}$ why does $y = \theta$? and why does $dx dy dz = r dr d\theta dz$

Comment: The transformation $(x,y,z)\mapsto (r,\theta,z)$ is given by $$\begin{align}x&=r\cos(\theta)\\\\y&=r\sin(\theta)\\\\z&=z\end{align}$$In addition we have $$dx\,dy\,dz=r\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$$

Answer (score 2):

This comes from the [Jacobian](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/changeofvariables.aspx). We have Jacobian
$$
\left|\dfrac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(r,\theta,z)}\right| = \begin{vmatrix} \cos \theta & -r \sin \theta & 0 \\ \sin \theta & r \cos \theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{vmatrix}= r\cos^2 \theta + r \sin^2 \theta= r
$$
This is just example 3 from the link, just in cylindrical coordinates, where $z=z$ does not really change anything, so the Jacobian really just comes from the 'polar part'.